# Layout Issue: 3-Button Navigation and Notification UI Bar Misplacement in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, layout, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-navigation-bar

I'm encountering a layout problem in Virtual Phone Android Studio where the 3-button navigation is shifting to the top of the screen, while the notification UI bar is moving to the bottom.

I tried various troubleshooting steps, including changing the AVD, reinstalling Android Studio, and creating a new project, the problem persists. Additionally, I tried an alternative approach of enabling the auto-rotate feature on the Android device and rotating the AVD accordingly, but to no avail. Are there any additional suggestions or solutions I can try to resolve this issue?

I want the AVD to look like it should, where the navigation buttons are at the bottom of the screen and the UI bar is at the top.

Image 1:
[Navigation & UI Bar misplacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi84j.png)

Image 2:
[UI Position after rotating AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmY2F.png)

#AVD #AndroidStudio